# Java applet with files amomg several subfolders

Tags: java, applet, embed, subdirectory

I have a Java program that includes several directories and I would like to turn it into an applet. For that purpose I have embedded the class which will have the `start` and `paint` methods like so:

```
<applet code="appletClass.class" width="450" height="420" codebase="myProgram/bin/">
</applet>
```

Now, the `appletClass.class` file is in `myProgram/bin/`, but other classes that `appletClass.class` calls to and instantiates are among several other folders (some are `myProgram/bin/ca`, `myProgram/bin/de`). Does the JVM automatically know which subfolder to look for if I use `import` statements in `appletClass.java` or is there some way to include multiple subdirectories in the embedding so that when I instantiate objects defined in different directories the application works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to first create a jar file consisting all your class files as [follows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

then follow the below instructions

Sun developed a generic JavaScript to handle all the specific browser quirks, so that you don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Add this to your  section:

```
<script src="//www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
```

And this to  section:

```
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase: 'http://my.url/my/path/to/codebase',
                      code: 'my.main.Applet.class',
                      archive: 'my-archive.jar',
                      width: '800', 
                      height: '600'};
    var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
    var version = '1.5'; // JDK version
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

See [Java™ Rich Internet Applications Deployment Advice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for a detailed explanation of the script and all the possible options.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't suppose I can just use my .jar file which was compiled using the main class (having the method public static void main(string args[]))? I have to implement init(), start(), and paint() and then create a jar file?

Comment: @WhiteTiger, yeah you can't just run your previous jar file and expect it to run as an applet. you need to write a proper applet class

Answer (score 1):

> Does the JVM automatically know which subfolder to look for if I use import statements..?

Yes it does.

But then, Oracle recently cracked down on the security environment of applets to the point that an unsigned applet is unlikely to get launched at all.  So follow the advice of @sasankad and Jar the classes (then digitally sign them).